# Integrate JTabbedPane into already made GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout, jtabbedpane

I created a GUI with a JFrame and a contentPanel. This contentPanel was one aspect of my gui. I have now decided I want to further develop this GUI, and want to have a JTabbedPanel in it.
I want the contentPanel that is currently displaying to be one of the tabs in the JTabbedPane.

Essentially, I want my JFrame, with a JPanel that has JTabbedPane, and within these tabs I want to put JPanel(s). I'm also using GridBagLayout on the JPanel that currently displays the GUI, and it's making everything hard.

Someone please help.
Here are some screenshots. [Current GUI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgHVl.png) [Here's what I want it to be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s02B.png)

Here's my GUI Code:
``java

public GUI() {

```
    loadRegPlateArray();

    
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(500, 200, 1000, 600);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 131, 160, 114, 16, 117, 147, 246, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 75, 56, 50, 61, 55, 69, 56, 40, 40, 10, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);
    
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    
    comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(cl.regArray));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_comboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_comboBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_comboBox.gridx = 2;
    gbc_comboBox.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(comboBox, gbc_comboBox);
    
    
    
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add new car");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnNewButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 3;
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton, gbc_btnNewButton);
    
    rest of the content of the gui (jlabels etc)
```

```
Thank you!
```

Comment: Start over. Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tabbed Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html). Then you create one panel for each tab and add the panel to the tabbed pane.

Comment: @camickr am i not able to copy my panel over into a tabbed pane?

Comment: Of course you can. That is how a tabbed pane works. You add a panel to the tabbed pane. Did you not read the tutorial and download the code? What part of the code did you not understand?

Comment: I am still very confused, GridBagLayout is making everything almost impossible!

Comment: You were given a link to a working example. I can't guess what your problem is.